# Is it possible in Scala to make a function that disallows the use of closures?

Tags: scala, scope, closures

Say I have some function like this:

```
def doSomeCode(code: => Unit): Unit = {
  println("Doing some code!")
  code
}
```

It takes in a function, prints out "Doing some code!" and then calls the passed function. If for example we called it like:

```
doSomeCode {
  println("Some code done!")
}
```

It would print out "Doing some code!", followed by "Some code done!".

But I would like to disallow the use of outside variables inside that code block, for example:

```
def otherFunction(): Unit = {
  val number = 10

  doSomeCode{
    println("The number is " + number)
  }
}
```

This will print out "Doing some code!", followed by "The number is 10". But I would like it to instead throw an error because I do not want `number` to be in the scope of doSomeCode. Is this possible to achieve in Scala?
To be clear I am not asking if this is a good idea, I just want to know if it is possible.

Edit:
The reason I want this is because I am trying to make a syntax that is perfectly functional, I want a block with no side effects. Ideally the syntax would look like:

```
val a = 1
val b = 2
val c = 3
val d = 4

val sum = use(a, c, d){
  val total = a + c + d
  total
}
```

This way I as a programmer know that the only variables used are `a`, `c`, and `d` and that `sum` is the only output. Trying to use anything else, eg `b`, would result in an error. Currently it is not possible to know at a glance what variables a block is using. I can achieve this by just making and using a function like this:

```
def example(): Unit = {
  val a = 1
  val b = 2
  val c = 3
  val d = 4

  val sum = sum(a, c, d)
}

def sum(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int): Int = {
  val total = a + b + c
  total
}
```

This behaves exactly like how I want it to, but I would like it to be inline with the other code, not outside as an external function.

Comment: I doubt it is possible. It may be doable with some macros, but that won't be easy. Any reason why you want this? Sounds like an **XY problem**.

Comment: Edited the post with an explanation. Basically I just want a scope block that has zero possible side effects

Comment: That is a noble cause, but it is lost. Printing is a side effect, reading the clock is a side effect. You can do a lot of things without accessing anything external. Finally, all the variables are in scope, and since they are not mutated reading them is not a side effect. - Anyways, have you looked at `cats.effect.IO` basically, it you have a value inside an **IO** it can only be used on a `flatMap` call. That is the closest that I know for this.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more specific. I am okay with side effects on variables passed in, standard IO, normal language calls. What I want specifically is for the code in the block to behave like it is in a function defined elsewhere, but inline. See recent edit

Comment: Why don't you simply always encapsulate the code within a function that takes parameters? This way you know exactly at a glance which are the free variables of the closure.

Comment: What about something like `def use[T](scope: T)(block: T => Unit): Unit = block(scope)`. **T** can be any tuple so `use((a, b, c)) { case (a, b, c) => ... }`. But anyways, this is just more verbose, and I still fail to see what are you wining with this. This is still another function, and it is not being inlined by the compiler _(probably the **JIT** will do it)_.

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> def mkClosure(i: Int) = { s: String => s"$i - $s" }
mkClosure: (i: Int)String => String

scala> mkClosure(5)
res0: String => String = <function1>
```

Since whether the function depends on values which aren't parameters isn't encoded in the type system, there's no compiler-enforceable difference in Scala between such a function and a pure one.  It's unlikely to be possible with macros: a compiler plugin is probably your best bet, especially if you want to allow certain values (e.g. `println`) to be used inside a block.